# Pandas dataframe frequency operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I just start with pandas and I would like to know how to count the number of document(unique) per year per company

My data are : 
df

```
  year  document_id  company
0   1999    3     Orange
1   1999    5     Orange
2   1999    3     Orange
3   2001    41    Banana
4   2001    21    Strawberry
5   2001    18    Strawberry
6   2002    44    Orange
```

At the end, I would like to have a new dataframe like this

```
  year    document_id  company nbDocument
0   1999    [3,5]     Orange       2
1   2001    [21]      Banana       1
2   2001    [21,18]   Strawberry   2
3   2002    [44]      Orange       1
```

I tried :

```
count2 = apyData.groupby(['year','company']).agg({'document_id': pd.Series.value_counts})
```

But with `groupby` operation, I'm not able to have this kind of structure and count unique value for Orange in 1999 for example, is there a way to do this ?

Thx

Comment: Shouldn't the `document_id` of  `Banana` be  `[41]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `DataFrame` and add the unique `document_id` using a `list comprension` as follows:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
result['document_id'] = df.groupby(['company', 'year']).apply(lambda x: [d for d in x['document_id'].drop_duplicates()])
```

now that you have a list of unique `document_id`, you only need to get the length of this list:

```
result['nbDocument'] = result.document_id.apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

to get:

```
result.reset_index().sort_values(['company', 'year'])

      company  year document_id  nbDocument
0      Banana  2001        [41]           1
1      Orange  1999      [3, 5]           2
2      Orange  2002        [44]           1
3  Strawberry  2001    [21, 18]           2
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired output:

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = df.groupby(['year', 'company'])
out['nbDocument'] = grouped.apply(lambda x: list(x['document_id'].drop_duplicates()))
out['document_id'] = out['nbDocument'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
print(out.reset_index().sort_values(['year', 'company']))

   year     company nbDocument  document_id
0  1999      Orange     [3, 5]            2
1  2001      Banana       [41]            1
2  2001  Strawberry   [21, 18]            2
3  2002      Orange       [44]            1
```